# ¿Cómo agrego un nuevo elemento a un vector en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

Empecé recién a usar y entender en JavaScript y estoy tratando de entender cómo trabajar con vectores.
Cree un vector:

```
let miVector = [];
```

Quiero agregar un nuevo elemento al final del vector.
¿Cuál es la forma más fácil de hacerlo?
Averigüe, pero me siento confundida con los métodos disponibles como `push()`, `concat()`, entre otros. ¿Me pueden explicar cómo puedo lograr esto de una manera sencilla?

Answer (score 1):

`push` es el que mejor cumple con ese propósito.

```js
let vector = [];
vector.push(1, 2, 3);
console.log(vector);
```

---

Cuando tengas dudas puedes ver qué tiene la documentación para decirte.

- [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) agrega un elemento al final del arreglo.
- [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) crea un nuevo arreglo con los elementos de los otros 2 en el mismo orden.

```js
// Ejemplo de la documentación
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
const array3 = array1.concat(array2);

// Si imprimes los otros 2 arreglos, verás que no cambiaron
console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

De manera simplificada, intentaré explicar lo máximo sobre **arrays** en *JavaScript* partiendo desde el principio.

Los arrays en JavaScript tienen tamaños dinámicos, a diferencia de otros lenguajes, el tamaño del array no se declara así:

```
var array[13]
```

Esta sintaxis no existe en JavaScript, un array que tiene un límite de 13 elementos podría limitar el array.

La declaración del array es simple:

```
var array = []
```

Una vez declarado, puedes agregar números, letras e incluso tipos booleanos al array. Es importante mencionar que los arrays tienen índices y valores, y los índices en todos los arrays en todos los lenguajes comienzan en la posición "cero".

Por ejemplo:

| índice | valor |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `M` |
| `1` | `L` |

El índice representa la posición que ocupa en el array el valor insertado, una dirección donde se accede para encontrar el valor guardado en el array.

```js
var array1 = []; // Crea un nuevo array vacío.
array1[0] = "Sanji"; // Asigna "Sanji" a la primera posición del array.
array1[1] = "Nami"; // Asigna "Nami" a la segunda posición del array.
console.log(array1); // Muestra el contenido del array en la consola.
```

O obteniendo un valor específico por su índice:

```
console.log(array1[0]);
```

El método [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) añade al final del array:

```js
var array2 = []; // Crea un nuevo array vacío.
array2.push("Zoro"); // Añade "Zoro" al final del array.
array2.push("Yohohohoho"); // Añade "Yohohohoho" al final del array.
console.log(array2); // Muestra el contenido del array en la consola.
```

En un array pueden añadirse tipos diferentes y cambiarse teniendo como referencia el índice que representa el valor en el array:

```js
var array3 = [1, "Franky", 2]; // Crea un array con valores numéricos y de cadena.
array3[2] = "5"; // Modifica el valor en la tercera posición por "5".
array3[12] = 2; // Añade el valor 2 en la posición 12.
console.log(array3); // Muestra el contenido del array en la consola.
```

Observando el resultado de este array se presentará "[ 1, 'Frank', '5', <9 empty items>, 2 ]", aunque pases el índice directamente y saltes a una posición mayor, en la consola se mostrará el mensaje "<9 empty items>", indicando que hay nueve espacios vacíos consecutivos en el array que no han sido ocupados con ningún otro valor.

También existe la posibilidad de crear un nuevo array usando el constructor de objetos:

```js
var array4 = new Array(); // Crea un nuevo array vacío usando la sintaxis alternativa.
array4.push("Jinbe"); // Añade "Jinbe" al final del array.
array4[1] = "Ussop"; // Reemplaza el valor en la segunda posición por "Ussop".
array4.push("Luffy"); // Añade "Luffy" al final del array.
array4.push("chopper", 6, "Kaido")
console.log(array4); // Muestra el contenido del array en la consola.
```

El método [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) combina dos o más arrays creando un nuevo array:

```js
var x = array1.concat(array2.concat(array3))
console.log(x)
```